# FileOutputStream failing to write into a file or produce files

Tags: java, byte, output, fileoutputstream

i need some help here.
I am trying to write bytes into a file with FileOutputStream...
But the file does not appear in the directory as the jar file i build.
Or if i try in other ways, it would not write anything into the file even flushing files.

Here are my current codes:

```
 File ModFile =new File(NameText.getText() + ".mod");
FileOutputStream writer = null;

String toProcess = CodesBox.getText();
int i = Integer.parseInt(CodesBox.getText());
byte codes = (byte) i;  

try {
    writer = new FileOutputStream(ModFile);
    writer.write(codes);

} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ModMakerGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}finally{
    try {
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: what is the path of `ModFile` and where is your executable located?

Comment: 1. Is this code really getting executed? 2. If it is getting executed, what is the current working directory?

Comment: You can check where your file will be actually created with [`File.getAbsolutePath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29).

Comment: @jlordo The ModFile is the same directory as the jar file that is created.

Comment: @junyi00 let me be more specific: What does `System.out.println("'" + ModFile.getAbsolutePath() + "'");`print, and what is the path of your program?

Answer (score 0):

@junyi00 For me the file is created. And it shows as movie clip. I think the file should have been created for you too. Just try to see where it is created. Or check your classes `NameText` and `CodesBox` whether they are having any error somewhere. Check what is the file name generated.

Comment: Movie clip? i don't think the file created is a .mov file but a .mod file. NameText and CodesBox are definitely having no errors, NameText is the TextField and CodesBox is an Text Area

Comment: @junyi00  Although the file looks like a movie clip. It's readable through another java file. I read the file using this code. And it's reading well. `FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("abc.mod");  
  int i;  
  while((i=fis.read() ) != -1){  
    System.out.println("i: "+i);  
  }`  You are converting the input text into byte. If the text is more, I think you should better try with `byte[]` since the single byte variable has limitation. Or if you can provide what data you are trying with, probably I can help you more.